# Can't get diff output from NestedStack in AWS CDK

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, infrastructure, infrastructure-as-code

I have an issue when I'm working with NestedStack in AWS CDK, the problem is when I'm using the `cdk diff` command its returns the diff output return to me.

But when I have a diff inside my NestedStack it's just a reference and i really don't know what it will change inside my NestedStack.

```
[~] AWS::CloudFormation::Stack IAMPolicyStack.NestedStack/IAMPolicyStack.NestedStackResource IAMPolicyStackNestedStackIAMPolicyStackNestedStackResource4B98A1D2 
 ├─ [~] NestedTemplate
 │   └─ [~] .Resources:
 │       └─ [~] .CDKMetadata:
 │           └─ [~] .Properties:
 │               └─ [~] .Analytics:
 │                   ├─ [-] v2:deflate64:H4sIAAAAAAAA/zPSMzLWM1BMLC/WTU7J1s3JTNKr9kstLklNCS5JTM7WcU7LC0otzi8tSk4FsZ3z81IySzLz82p1AipLMvLz9I31DA30TBSzijMzdYtK80oyc1P1giA0AJZoScZcAAAA
 │                   └─ [+] v2:deflate64:H4sIAAAAAAAA/zPSMzLWM1BMLC/WTU7J1s3JTNKr9kstLklNCS5JTM7WcU7LC0otzi8tSk4FsZ3z81IySzLz82p1AipLMvLz9I31LPUMjRSzijMzdYtK80oyc1P1giA0ALbtmvJcAAAA
```

Hope someone out there has hit the same issue as me and has a solution about how to get the diff output from NestedStack.

**Updated 30/05/2022**

The featuer look like its not ready yet, but its coming in the feature based my ticket here - https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/20392

Answer (score 1):

[This commit](https://github.com/StevePotter/aws-cdk/commit/f58751aaef25a2bc5672730d737600e5536d175e) adds a workaround where you can run

```bash
cdk deploy --no-execute
```

and then view the nested stack changes in the CloudFormation change set that gets created.

Edit: Looks like this has not been merged yet as of 1.163.1, [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/19224) is the open issue.